# Why am I getting this strange error when typing a number?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm testing my C knowledge these days, and I was writing a tiny program about `if`/`else` statements.

The code should work (I hope so), because it worked a few compiles before, but now for some reason it throws this error:

[image: Error image]

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() { /*int main() { simply brought back the same error, I know it's the right one.*/
    int myNum;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    myNum == scanf("%d");
    if(myNum > 14) {
        printf("Your number is bigger than 14.");
    } else if(myNum == 14) {
        printf("Your number is equal to 14.");
    } else if(myNum > 14) {
        printf("Your number is smaller than 14.");
    } else {
        printf("Oops, not a number !");
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Read the [scanf manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and search for tutorials on how to use it. I very much doubt this code works anywhere. It needs to be `int result = scanf("%d", &myNum);`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will try that and inform you :)

Comment: Also, `==`  is a comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: are you writing code on your phone?

Comment: Who told you that `scanf` returned the number it read?  Did you guess?  Please don't guess.

Comment: @yano I was wondering that, too.  Pretty cool, I guess!  (Better not indulge in too much UB, though -- might end up with [demons coming out of the phone](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)!)

Comment: @SteveSummit haha, hopefully the masks are keeping those somewhat in check. Cool for the novelty, but I want no part of that. I could only survive two touchscreen keyboards before I had to get a blackberry with a physical keyboard. Typing on that is better, but still not something I look forward to. I'm afraid by next phone, touchscreen will be the only choice.

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 1):

**Advice for beginners: Always compile with warnings enabled, and heed them.** (We all were beginners at some point and we all have learned that the hard way ;-) ).

Visual Studio with /G4 offers the following ones:

```
1>C:\Users\Peter\source\repos\scanf-mistake\scanf-mistake.c(8,20): warning C4473: 'scanf' : not enough arguments passed for format string
1>C:\Users\Peter\source\repos\scanf-mistake\scanf-mistake.c(8,20): message : placeholders and their parameters expect 1 variadic arguments, but 0 were provided
1>C:\Users\Peter\source\repos\scanf-mistake\scanf-mistake.c(8,20): message : the missing variadic argument 1 is required by format string '%d'
1>C:\Users\Peter\source\repos\scanf-mistake\scanf-mistake.c(8,11): warning C4553: '==': result of expression not used; did you intend '='?
1>C:\Users\Peter\source\repos\scanf-mistake\scanf-mistake.c(21,5): warning C4098: 'main': 'void' function returning a value
1>C:\Users\Peter\source\repos\scanf-mistake\scanf-mistake.c(5): fatal error C1075: '{': no matching token found
```

The first one is the key here: you are missing the address where `scanf` is supposed to store the input. The next two are helpful attempts to explain it.

`'==': result of expression not used; did you intend '='?` is spot-on. `==` is the logical comparison. In C it is perfectly legal to have a simple expression instead of a "statement"; in fact, C is a bit strange in that, I think, all "statements" that are not declarations are in fact expressions: if `i` is an `int`, `i=10` is an integer expression and can be used as the right hand side in an assignment: `int k = i = 10;`. The same way `myNum == scanf("%d", &i)` is an integer expression and can be used in e.g. `if(myNum == scanf("%d", &i)) { /* use i */ }`. Read the scanf documentation (google `man scanf`) to understand what it returns: It is not the scanned value.

`'main': 'void' function returning a value` is true: `main` should be declared to return int.

The last error is probably just a copy/paste error: You likely forgot to copy the closing curly brace over.